# Prolog List Length

Tags: prolog

I'm practicing for my exam in prolog and I came across a question asking me how long this list would be:    `[One|[Two,[Three,[Four]]]]`. When I looked at the answers it said 3, but I can't figure out why it is 3. Could someone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `|` operator divide a list in a "head" (`One`, in your example) and a "tail" (`[Two,[Three,[Four]]]`) where the "tail" is a list, the part of the complete list (head plus tail) that follows the head.

So writing

```
[One|[Two,[Three,[Four]]]]
```

is like writing

```
[One, Two, [Three,[Four]]]
```

that is a list with three elements.

Comment: Hmm I think I see it now, the brackets just really confused me. Made me think it was 2 elements instead of 3. Thank you!

Comment: @LuukLooijenga a list of one or more elements can be written as `[H | T]` where `H` is the first element, and `T` is the *rest* or the *tail* and is, itself, a list. If you found max66's answer satisfactory, you should accept it (click the checkmark).

Comment: ... and thus the length of the list  `[H | T]` is one more than the length of the list `T`.